# How do I match the range of a distance driver to the value range of a key shape?

Tags: rigging, drivers, shape-keys

I have a key shape of SUSPENSION going from fully squashed to fully stretched.

[image: The range of the key shape]

The key shape is for the suspension of this vehicle rig.

[image: The rig]

The key shape is 100% weighted to an IK bone.

I've also created **two small cubes** that are weighted to the bones directly above and below the key shape (the varying distance between these two cubes will be used by the driver).

[image: Two cubes to create a distance relationship]

The maximum distance the cubes will be apart is ¬2.6 blender units.  (Blunits?)
The minimum distance is ¬0.7 blunits.

I put a driver on the Shape Key value, and set this to Sum Values, then selected the two small cubes to provide the distance.

[image: Driver details]

I've moved one of the cubes closer & farther from each other and the driver works! The key shape of the suspension changes.

Now I need to adjust the range of this distance driver so that it matches to where the min + max values need to be in relation to the rig.

...but I don't know how.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thanks!

[image: The desired outcome]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to setup Driver's F-curve. It shows how distance between objects (horizontal)  corresponds to  Shape Key value (Vertical):

[image]

So if distance 0.7 corresponds to Shape Key value of 0 and 2.6 corresponds to 1, You need to create a line between this 2 dots in drivers window:

[image]

Comment: 1: Crantisz, this worked!  Thank you. :)  

2: How I actually solved this was when I discovered that the driver would work when I manually moved the two cubes apart (G + mouse move the cube thereby making the driver respond), however the driver DID NOT RESPOND when I moved the cubes apart via the bones in pose mode (giving me false results). 

This is because I weight painted the cube in place instead of parenting the cube to the appropriate bone.  When I removed the weight painting, then parented the cubes to their bones I could then adjust the driver's F-curves and get proper results.

Comment: I finally understand the Driver Editor thanks to your answer and infoGRAPHic (punintended).